# Exploded directory jar deployment jboss eap

Tags: maven, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I have a maven project which contains properties files.I would like to deploy the jar as exploded directory jar using maven plugins.

Any help or insights appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need help with the Maven or the JBoss EAP-side of this?

For the JBoss EAP side, in 7.1 there are now management interface functions that help with managing exploded deployments:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html-single/configuration_guide/#managing_exploded_deployments